# Can't encode cyrillic character in python 2.7.x

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

When I trying to encode cyrillic "Р" character I get errors. Here is my code and errors:

```
>>> "Р".encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to solve it. Please help me. I'm using Python 2.7.x. Thank you for every advice.

**EDITED:**

```
def _to_unicode_or_bust(self, obj, encoding='utf-8'):
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
            obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
    return obj
```

I get above method from presentation. It's work in terminal and simple python file. It's not work in OpenERP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything in `""` (e.g. a `str`) in Python 2.x is already encoded. You need to decode it to a `unicode` before you can encode it as something else.

["Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Better yet, if we're starting with a literal, create a Unicode literal (`u"Р"`) in the first place.

Comment: It's working on terminal and simple python file. But it's now work on OpenERP. See my edited.

Comment: A PowerPoint slide seems like a poor way of demystifying things.

Answer (score 0):

Python's interpreter starts in an ascii-only mode so you can't input Cyrllic characters directly.  Instead you can create them by their code point numbers:

```
>>> print unichr(0x420)
Р
>>> unichr(0x420).encode('utf-8')
'\xd0\xa0'
```

or by their names:

```
>>> u'\N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ER}'.encode('utf-8')
'\xd0\xa0'
```